# Why aren't Bayesian models straightforwardly superior to all/most other models if they model the real-world better?

Tags: bayesian

Why aren't Bayesian models straightforwardly superior to all/most other models if they model the real-world better?

As possibly displayed by the following chart:

[image]

[source](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Rens-Schoot/publication/257749007/figure/tbl1/AS:669647019970566@1536667699316/Overview-of-the-Similarities-and-Differences-Between-Frequentist-and-Bayesian-Statistics.png)

Comment: What is your definition of "straightforwardly superior"?

Comment: @Craig That they can explain all the things that other models can and more.

Comment: The no free lunch theorem. There is no known universal "as good or better" for all cases. You can search here and on crossvalidated for more info. I also use the terms good and better loosely. A bayesian model might perform better as measured one metric and worse by another metric.

Comment: @Craig I don't know. I believed that Bayesian will cover all bases, because it can reproduce the distributions of all variables and also incorporate beliefs. OTOH, other models are always some other models than the exact distributions. The question is about trying to verify these.